# ¿Cómo podría hacer este código responsive usando Tailwind?

Tags: html, css, tailwind

aqui dejare la imagen que estoy usando:

```
https://www.bbva.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/turismo_sostenible.jpg
```

lo que necesito es cuando pase esta web a un telefono se vea bien, no deforme usando responsive con tailwind

a continuacion mostrare como es normalmente el html y como queda con responsive
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<header>
  <!-- Aca esta la url de la imagen del banner -->
  <div class="w-full h-screen bg-cover" style="background-image: url('touris.png');">
    <div class="absolute top-1/2 left-1/4 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 text-black text-4xl font-bold">
      <h1 class="font-mono text-5xl">DiscoverEase</h1>
      <h2 class="font-extralight text-5xl">Las mejores experiencias</h2>
    </div>
  
    <!-- BOTONES DE HIPERBINCULOS -->
    <div class="flex flex-row">
      <div class="w-screen h-full bg-black bg-opacity-70">
        <nav class="W-full flex justify-self-start text-white text-sm">
          <button class="m-5 focus:text-base cursor-pointer">Inicio</button>
          <button class="m-5 focus:text-base cursor-pointer">Proyectos</button>
          <button class="m-5 focus:text-base cursor-pointer">experiencias</button>

          <!-- BARRA BUSCAR -->
          <div class="m-4">
            <form class="flex items-center">
              <div class="relative flex-grow">
                <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3 pointer-events-none">
                  <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 4a4 4 0 100 8 4 4 0 000-8zM2 8a6 6 0 1110.89 3.476l4.817 4.817a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-4.816-4.816A6 6 0 012 8z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="w-60 flex-grow bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 pl-10 p-1 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="Busca tu viaje deseado" required>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="bg-gray-900 inline-flex items-center py-1 px-3 ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-gray-600- rounded-lg border bg-opacity-70">
                <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-5 h-5 mr-2 -ml-1" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M21 21l-6-6m2-5a7 7 0 11-14 0 7 7 0 0114 0z"></path>
                </svg>
                Buscar
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>

          <!-- INICIAR SESION Y CREAR CUENTA -->
          <div class="flex-grow"></div> <!-- Espacio flexible para empujar el botón a la derecha -->
          <button class="mr-5">Acceder</button>
          <button class="mr-5">Registrate</button>
          <button class="mr-5 w-12"> <img src="ico.png" alt=""></button>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: En lugar de `w-full` y `h-screen` usa `max-w-full` y `h-auto`. #### Referencias
- [Imagen responsiva con Tailwind CSS](https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/content-styles/images/)